# i want to retrieve current logged user data from firestore but this show error

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

> Attempt to invoke virtual method com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a `null` object reference :

**MyAccount.java**

```
public class MyAccount extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private TextView email,passwordtxt;
    private FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;
    private String UserId;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_account);

        email       = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email_txt);
        UserId      = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        passwordtxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pass_txt);
        mAuth       = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirestore  = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        mFirestore.collection("Hospitals")
                  .document(UserId).get()
                  .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                String user_name = documentSnapshot.getString("email");
                String password  = documentSnapshot.getString("password");

                email.setText(user_name);
                passwordtxt.setText(password);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @SantanuSur it's not comes under as you make possible duplicate...

Comment: `mAuth` is null @GowthamanM its clearly a duplicate !!

Comment: @SantanuSur yes i know..but as you make possible duplicate not a android related tag.

Comment: if not added a proper tag the question should be **editted** with **that tag** and then should be flagged as such !! @GowthamanM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `onCreate` method code to :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_account);

    email = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email_txt);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    UserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    passwordtxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pass_txt);

    mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
   mFirestore.collection("Hospitals").document(UserId).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            String user_name = documentSnapshot.getString("email");
            String password  = documentSnapshot.getString("password");


            email.setText(user_name);
            passwordtxt.setText(password);
        }
    });    
}
```

Comment: bro, i cannot find what is the difference between your code and my code

Comment: just copy and paste it in your code you will find it... As you can see mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); must be initialized before using it...

Comment: @SharmaBlog you need to get Instance 1st **mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()** then get user id  **UserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();** check carefully..

Comment: Thanks, bro it's working

Comment: @SharmaBlog welcome... Happy Coding.. :) upvote will be appiricated..